# ASP core navigation between applications on same domain

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, web-applications, .net-core, razor-pages

I have one domain and 3 web applications (and I'll have much more).

I would like to create the main application which will contain some list with links and description about these applications.

I have the main application in `IIS` and then others like sub-applications. I would like to navigate between them like [mydomain.com/app1/then/something](http://#) and [mydomain.com/app2/index](http://#)...

When I create pure `HTML` (using `<a href="">`) everything is working, but when I create a web application - there is problem.

In `Firefox` I get only white screen when I try to access sub-application 
(e.g. [mydomain.com/app1](http://#)) and in `Chrome` HTTP 500.

I am using `Razor pages`.
I expect that this is a problem with routing so I'll have to change some routing conditions or map the other apps.

Could you give me a hint, please? I tried to search for some solutions, but I couldn't find one (I was probably searching bad sentence).

Thank you for every advice.

Edit: Added logs

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-09-25 07:33:35
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET / - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 - 200 0 0 1771
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /css/site.css - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 304 0 0 9
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 304 0 0 10
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /css/site.min.css v=kHvJwvVAK1eJLN4w8xygUR3nbvlLmRwi5yr-OuAO90E 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 304 0 0 9
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /js/site.min.js v=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 200 0 0 5
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 304 0 0 2
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /js/site.js v=dLGP40S79Xnx6GqUthRF6NWvjvhQ1nOvdVSwaNcgG18 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 304 0 0 4
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 304 0 0 4
2018-09-25 07:33:35 10.208.132.246 GET /favicon.ico - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 - 200 0 0 50
2018-09-25 07:33:43 10.208.132.246 GET /App1/ - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 https://example.com:12443/ 500 19 183 43
2018-09-25 07:33:46 10.208.132.246 GET /App1 - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 - 500 19 183 42
2018-09-25 07:33:54 10.208.132.246 GET /App2 - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 - 500 19 183 44
2018-09-25 07:34:03 10.208.132.246 GET /App2/App2SpecificPage/Parameter - 12443 - 10.217.165.172 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 - 500 19 183 42
```

Comment: *What* is not working? Surely you can specify links to your application; there is nothing in ASP.NET Core that would prevent you from doing that.

Comment: I've edited my question - whats not working - i get only white screen or http 500..

Comment: So I was thinking that webapplication is thinking that /app1 could be some parameter or something like that

Comment: Error 500 means that there is a problem with the web application on the server. You should check your server logs. There is nothing we can help you with unless we know the actual problem that occurs.

Comment: Btw. note that you will have to use `app.UsePathBase("/app1")` to add the middleware that enables your application to be able to run in a subpath of the domain.

Comment: I've checked my logs and there is only my `get` request.. Is there any possibility to get more informations, pleaase? I tried to add this to middleware, but same problem.

Comment: Your server logs. There should be more information.

Comment: Only thing which I can see in these logs are HTTP Get/Post...

Comment: Can you post the logs? Did you reduce the logging level?

Comment: Logs added to post. I didn't changed anything - it should be default logging.Report log format `W3C`

Comment: Those are IIS logs, but you should be looking for your ASP.NET Core application logs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I turned on logging factory, but there was nothing in logs which could helped me. I rewied IIS settings once more and again added applications to middleware and now it's working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thaks to [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)

My problem was combination of missing `app.UsePathBase("/app1")` in application `Startup.cs` file and bad settings in IIS.

But main problem was that I didn't added application to the middleware.